# Looping divs in a div works, but adjusting position does not

Tags: javascript, loops, html

I am making a webpage. I have one main DIV (relative) with lots of DIV's(absolutes) inside. I want to change the position and size of DIV's inside the main DIV with javascript.

This works. Got it from stackoverflow. Loops trough al the divs and gives me the information i want to change. Size and position.

```
function getDivs(){ 
var loopdiv = document.getElementById('loopdiv');
var divs=loopdiv.getElementsByTagName('div') 

for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){ 

alert("left:"+divs[i].style.left
 +"   top:"+divs[i].style.top
 +"   height:"+divs[i].style.height
 +"   width:"+divs[i].style.width
 ); 

}  }
```

So i thought let's change it up. Let's add little code so all my div's are at 0,0 position.

```
function getDivs(){ 
var loopdiv = document.getElementById('loopdiv');
var divs=loopdiv.getElementsByTagName('div') 

for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){ 

divs[i].style.left=0;
divs[i].style.top=0;



}
```

Should be pretty crowded with div's right now on 0,0.... but nothing.
Every div just retains their initial position from the HTML.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: try adding `positon:absolute;`

Comment: I assume you've already positioned `#loopdiv div` absolutely?  Have you properly closed the function (I ask as the closing bracket is missing from your example)?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use JS?  You could accomplish this more easily with just CSS!  `#loopdiv div {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;}` But I assume you know that.

Comment: Yes it has to be with JS. It has to adjust to certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo!

Change

```
divs[i].sytle.top=0;
```

to

```
divs[i].style.top=0;
```

Comment: I made a big booboo. Forgot the }  :|   Okej i'm going to take a break now :P Think i need one if i forget the }